# Can not upload image to Spree app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I try to upload a product image to my Spree app, but i get this error

```
5errors prohibited this record from being saved:

Attachment Paperclip returned errors for file 'index.jpg' - check ImageMagick installation or image source file.
Attachment Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError
Attachment Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError
Attachment Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError
Attachment Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError
```

Should i install a gem, relocate my src image? Whats the problem here

Comment: Looks like you should to install ImageMagick. Check your ImageMagick version from command line: `$ identify -version`

Comment: What version of OS are you using?

Comment: I am using windows 10, with rails 5.1 and the latest stable spree gem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so the problem is pretty complicated and after trying to solve it for about 3 hours i finally got it.

1. First, you have to remove the convert.exe from your System32 files.
   We do this, because the Spree app relies on legacy code and when it
   tries to upload the image the default convert.exe starts, we don't
   want that.
2. Second you download and install the **dynamic** installation from the imagemagick site and you have to be sure to check the legacy support so the convert command gets supported.
3. I dont know if you have to, but i installed the paperclip gem. You may have to do that for it to work.

The whole reason this bug happens, is because Windows. So if you are new to this party, dual boot your station or swap to Ubuntu/Mac whatever. Seriously though, when the app tries to upload it uses the convert command, but convert is already a default Windows command so you can't upload the picture properly. So we disable the command and then we replace it with our imagemagick installation. That's it.Also good luck trying to delete the convert.exe from system32, its a weird process, but you can solve it with some google-fu.

Thanks to Michael for pointing me to right way.

Comment: It's really true - macOs that's the best environment for ruby/rails development, and Ubuntu for production stuff. With Windows too much pain :)

Answer (score 1):

You should to install ImageMagick. Follow these steps for install on Windows:

1. [Download](http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/ImageMagick/binaries/) ImageMagick (you need to choose **static** version for your 32/64 bit OS)
2. Checked **Add application directory to your system path** and install
3. Reopen your command prompt to reload your PATH variables
4. Run `convert -v` to check the install worked

Comment: I followed your instructions and converted an image, so magick works finew yet the problem persists, should i install a gem associated?

Comment: Should i place the image in a different directory maybe?

Comment: At convert -version i get invalid disk specification though. Maybe somewhere here is the problem

Comment: @ChristopherBovo You only need paperclip gem and configured Model. Can you show model, which have attachments and `convert -version` error?

Comment: Okay, so convert -v is considered legacy , the new way to check is magick -version. But maybe the reason it gets renamed is because i am on Windows and a convert command exists by default. I have posted the problem also on the imagemagick forums and i am awaiting a response there since its a fairly complicated problem it seems